# Problem With Sum

Tags: summation

I would like help with the following summation. Every time I come to this step in my signals class, I have difficulty proving that:

$$
\sum_{j=0}^{n-3}1=n-2
$$

Comment: Hint: you are summing up $\,(n-3) - (0) +1\,$ terms, and each term equals $1$. P.S. Please see this [MathJax primer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) the next time around.

Comment: OHH right thanks a lot i see it now!

Comment: You can use induction on $n$.

Comment: What precisely don't you understand ?

Comment: @SerkanYassıkaya  Please, if you are ok, you can accept the answer and set it as solved. Thanks! cdn.sstatic.net/img/faq/faq-accept-answer.png

Answer (score 1):

Simply note that

$$\sum_{j=0}^{n-3}=\stackrel{n-2 \, times}{1=1+1+...+1}=n-2$$

Answer (score 1):

The pattern is simple:

Let $S_n:=\sum_{j=0}^{n-3}1$. We have

$$S_3=1_0=1,\\S_4=1_0+1_1=2,\\S_5=1_0+1_1+1_2=3,\\S_6=1_0+1_1+1_2+1_3=4,\\\cdots$$

(the indices are there to explicit the values of $j$).

Answer (score 1):

Increment the sum borders:
$$\sum_{j=0}^{n-3} 1 = \sum_{j=0+1}^{n-3+1} 1 = \sum_{j=1}^{n-2} 1 = $$
$$\underbrace{1+1+\cdots+1}_{n-2}=n-2.$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\sum_{j=0}^{n-3}1=n-2$$
Consider $\sum_{j=0}^{n-3}a_nx$
$$\sum_{j=0}^{n-3}a_jx=a_0x+\underbrace{a_1x+...a_{n-3}x}_{(n-3) terms } $$
Set $x=1$ and $a_j=1 $ for $j=0...$

So $(n-3)\times 1 +1=n-2$

Answer (score 0):

A basic summation identity is:
$$\sum_{j=1}^Nc=cN$$
With an extra term: $$\sum_{j=0}^Nc=c(1+N)$$